# 80GB HDD recently stopped appearing in "My Computer", appears in Disk Manager as unformattable 330GB HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

My PC recently shut down from overheating, and when I turned it back on I was told Windows couldn't boot because a device was missing.
Upon installing windows on a different HDD (Which I'll refer to from here as E) I opened disk manager, as the original HDD that had failed (Which I'll refer to as C) was still in my BIOS as a bootable drive.

Upon opening Drive Manager I was instantly told that a HDD needed initializing, and that it had a capacity of 330.54GB.
I Initialised it as an MBR and when that was finished I attempted to create a 30GB partition in the hopes to isolate the space that was causing the issues on C, but any attempt to format the drive always tries to format it to 330GB rather than the requested 30GB.

Does anyone know how I can solve this? I know an 80GB HDD sounds like a daft thing to worry over but I'm kind of on a budget here for parts.

Comment: I wouldn't waste any more time... The disk is failing and will result in more catastrophic data loss in the future... You can pick up a 320+GB replacement for about £30...

Comment: You should check its SMART parameters and do a short test at least.

Comment: What you describe is not possible.  It sounds like the disk isn't actually  80GB

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool that you can use called [AOMEI Partition Assistant](http://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html). You can use this to view the partitions on the HDD, and you can also delete them.

[image: AOMEI Partition Assistant]